# x-axis labels shifted off ggplot2 bar chart in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, geom-bar

I'm using geom_bar to plot the frequency of responses to a survey about introducing non-native species as pest control. I'm examining how responses to that question vary by where people live. Sample data [here](https://github.com/CaitLittlef/nwcasc-soc-eco/blob/master/temp_190812.csv).

I want to customize x-axis labels on a bar-chart. However, in trying to specify new values, they either disappear or get completely shifted to the right. If I run the code as is, below, the x-axis is automatically populated with the pest.intro.nonnat values (-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), as in Fig. 1.

But if I activate `scale_x_discrete()` then I lose any x-axis labels (Fig. 2). If I activate `xlim()` then I get the labels I want, but they're bumped 4 spaces to the right (Fig. 3).

Can someone help me get my desired labels in the proper place? Thank you!

```
p + geom_bar(aes(fill = desc.p18), stat = "count",
             position = "stack", col = "black") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2",
                    labels = legend,) + 
  # scale_x_discrete(labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")) +
  # xlim("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") +
  labs(title = "pest.intro.nonnat",
       y = "Number of responses") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=10, angle=45))
```

[image: Fig. 1 with no label specifications]

[image: Fig. 2 with scale_x_discrete specified]

[image: Fig 3. with xlim specified]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your x value are in factor if you wish to use `scale_x_discrete`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=as.factor(pest.intro.nonnat))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = desc.p18), stat = "count", position = "stack", col = "black") +  
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you -- such an easy fix! I'm still curious as to why the labels were offset (or gone) when the data were still numeric. Can you offer any explanation why that happened when using as to why the lower plot (with `xlim()`) looks the way it does?

Comment: It's offset simply because `scale_x_discrete` will automatically start from labelling from value 1 onwards.